# Is it possible to generate NSManagedObject subclasses in Swift?

Tags: xcode, core-data

I use Xcode 8.3. Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass ... creates only .m and .h files. There is no language option. How to get a swift version now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there is one:

- Select the `.xcdatamodeld` file in the navigation side bar.
- Select the entity.
- Press <kbd>⌥⌘1</kbd> (Identity and Type Inspector).
- Choose the language in `Core Data Model` > `Code Generation` > `Language`